# 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'?

Tags: swift, layout, uicollectionview

I am trying to write a custom Class to create a UICollectionView, which I intent to create multiple instances from in different classes. Below is the code I am using inside the custom UICollectionView Class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {



    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {

        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        setupCollectionView(topEdgeInset: 20, bottomEdgeInset: 20, leftEdgeInset: 20, rightEdgeInset: 20, screenWdith: frame.width, screenHeight: frame.height, minimumCellsHorizontalSpacing: 20, minimumCellsVerticalSpacing: 20, numberOfCellsPerRow: 2, viewCollectionViewWillBeAddedTo: self, dataSource: self as! UICollectionViewDataSource, delegate: self as! UICollectionViewDelegate)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    convenience init(topEdgeInset: CGFloat, bottomEdgeInset: CGFloat, leftEdgeInset: CGFloat, rightEdgeInset: CGFloat, screenWdith: CGFloat, screenHeight: CGFloat, minimumCellsHorizontalSpacing: CGFloat, minimumCellsVerticalSpacing: CGFloat, numberOfCellsPerRow: CGFloat, viewCollectionViewWillBeAddedTo: UIView, dataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource, delegate: UICollectionViewDelegate) {

        self.init(frame: viewCollectionViewWillBeAddedTo.bounds,collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

        setupCollectionView(topEdgeInset: topEdgeInset, bottomEdgeInset: bottomEdgeInset, leftEdgeInset: leftEdgeInset, rightEdgeInset: rightEdgeInset, screenWdith: screenWdith, screenHeight: screenHeight, minimumCellsHorizontalSpacing: minimumCellsHorizontalSpacing, minimumCellsVerticalSpacing: minimumCellsVerticalSpacing, numberOfCellsPerRow: numberOfCellsPerRow, viewCollectionViewWillBeAddedTo: viewCollectionViewWillBeAddedTo, dataSource: dataSource, delegate: delegate)

    }

    func setupCollectionView (topEdgeInset topInset: CGFloat, bottomEdgeInset bottomInset: CGFloat, leftEdgeInset leftInset: CGFloat, rightEdgeInset rightInset: CGFloat, screenWdith width: CGFloat, screenHeight height: CGFloat, minimumCellsHorizontalSpacing cellsHorizontalSpacing: CGFloat, minimumCellsVerticalSpacing cellsVerticalSpacing: CGFloat, numberOfCellsPerRow cellsPerRow: CGFloat, viewCollectionViewWillBeAddedTo hostView: UIView, dataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource, delegate: UICollectionViewDelegate) {

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)

        layout.minimumLineSpacing = cellsVerticalSpacing

        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = cellsHorizontalSpacing

        let widthOfCollectionViewCell: CGFloat = width - (leftInset + rightInset + cellsHorizontalSpacing) / cellsPerRow

        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: widthOfCollectionViewCell, height: 100)

        let myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: hostView.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        myCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")

        myCollectionView.dataSource = dataSource

        myCollectionView.delegate = delegate

        hostView.addSubview(self)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)

        myCell.backgroundColor = .blue

        return myCell
    }

}
```

The below class is where I created an instance from the above custom UICollectionView class:

```
class FirstItemInTabBarOpenRolledSections: UIViewController
{

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .black

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
_ = CustomCollectionView(topEdgeInset: 20, bottomEdgeInset: 20, leftEdgeInset: 20, rightEdgeInset: 20, screenWdith: self.view.frame.width, screenHeight: self.view.frame.height, minimumCellsHorizontalSpacing: 20, minimumCellsVerticalSpacing: 20, numberOfCellsPerRow: 2, viewCollectionViewWillBeAddedTo: self.view, dataSource: self as! UICollectionViewDataSource, delegate: self as! UICollectionViewDelegate)

    }
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("User tapped on itme \(indexPath.row)")

    }

}
```

However, every time I run the app it crashes and I get an error which says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

I do not understand my my layout is not initialised?? Could anyone plese spot where the problem is?

Comment: I rolled back your last big edit because posting working code in place of the original code makes the whole question unnecessary and voids the need for any answers. If anything, post your own answer with your working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear. You need to specify a layout when creating a collection view but you do not do so.

In your convenience `init` you call `self.init()` but you must call `self.init(frame:,collectionViewLayout:)`.

You will need to refactor your `setupCollectionView` method as part of getting this correct.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Following up on your answer, I modified the code inside the custom UICollectionView as well as the one inside the ViewController where I created the first instance from the custom UICollectionView class as illustraed above. However, now I am getting this error "Could not cast value of type 'EC3_Cross_Section_Classification.FirstItemInTabBarOpenRolledSections' (0x106f924d8) to 'UICollectionViewDataSource' (0x1128dfb70)."

Comment: That's a whole new issue for a new question.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I totally understand your point. I managed to sort out the problem, however, not fully as I desired, please have a look at the above updated code for how I solved the issue. In an ideal worl I would love to make the custom UICollectionView class handle everything related to the CollectionView that I would like to create multiple instances of in other ViewControllers later on. Even things such as:

Comment: myCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)

Comment: which are currently being dealt with in the UIViewController class.